# Filtering lookup on more than one related record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have the following setup with custom entities.

Incident (Service Case) related to Products

Tier 1 Complaint related to Products and Tier 2 Complaint

Tier 2 Complaint related to Products

I have customised the Incident form by adding the Tier 1 and Tier 2 fields. What I want is the user to select the Tier 1, but the values available being only those which have been related to the select Product on the form. This part is fairly easy to do.

The sticking point is the Tier 2 field. What I want is for the user to be limited to Tier 2 values which are filtered based upon the selected Tier 1 value AND the currently selected product. Out of the box, I can achieve one or the other using the Related Records Filtering but not both at the same time.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted by using javascript to create a view on the fly and setting this to be the default view.